# Jquery Datepicker UI Rails not display on Responsive Browser due to bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working on homepages with search bar, it's working fine.

as I am using Rails 5, Jquery UI datepicker

[image]

as you can see this screenshot as it display fine, when i try resize the browser on tablet or mobile size, as i am unable to click on the start day as it's wont appear on calendar month, i try check console log or bug but nothing came out

[image]

```
<!-- Tool list -->
<div class="searchbar">
    <%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mobile_searchbar_form">
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  id:"address-input", placeholder: t('whereneedequip'), class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 mobile_searchbar_form">
            <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                <i class="custom custom-icon-calender"></i>
                <%= text_field_tag :start_date, params[:start_date], id:"start_date", readonly: true, placeholder: t('startday') , class: "form-control datepicker" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 mobile_searchbar_form">
            <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                <i class="custom custom-icon-calender"></i>
                <%= text_field_tag :end_date, params[:end_date], id:"end_date", readonly: true, placeholder: t('endday') , class: "form-control datepicker", disabled: true %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 mobile_searchbar_form ">
            <%= submit_tag t('search'), class: "btn btn-black-free-account btn-block" %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
<script>
  $('#start_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '3m',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $('#end_date').datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
      $('#end_date').attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });

  $('#end_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '3m',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $('#start_date').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
    }
  });


</script>
```

update i have put script in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/slider
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery.raty
//= require holder
//= require turbolinks
//= require datatables
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require toastr
//= require moment 
//= require fullcalendar
//= require card
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick

//= require activestorage
//= require cable
//= require admin
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
//= require_tree ./channels


$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('#start_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '3m',
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $('#end_date').datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
          $('#end_date').attr("disabled", false);
        }
      });

      $('#end_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '3m',
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $('#start_date').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
        }
      });
});
```

I assume this is more Bootstrap front-end issue than rails issue.

**UPDATE**, *as it nothing do with JavaScript or pages, it down to bootstrap issue*

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 mobile_searchbar_form">
            <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
                <i class="custom custom-icon-calender"></i>
                <%= text_field_tag :start_date, params[:start_date], readonly: true,placeholder: t('startday') , class: "form-control datepicker" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 mobile_searchbar_form">
            <div class="inner-addon right-addon">

                <%= text_field_tag :end_date, params[:end_date], readonly: true, placeholder: t('endday') , class: "form-control datepicker" %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

when i remove "col-xs-6 col-md-2" on

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 mobile_searchbar_form">
```

into

```
<div class="mobile_searchbar_form">
```

then the calender appear on the mobile or tablet layout.

[image]

Comment: It isn't possible to provide a solution unless you can provide a reproducible example, here.

Comment: can u try moving your script inside to the application.js file or any other js file. ? add in `$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {` this function

Comment: yes, i have done but still same issue.